# POST data to another server and retrieve value

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to write a post method that will post a key/value pair to another server and capture the response. The key/value pair is there for security reasons and is a simple post.
The response comes back as an XML - ideally, I would like this mapped to an object as well.

Here's what I've done so far:

First, I checked to see if it would work using a simple form:

```
<form action="https://somesite.com/feed" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="value" /> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This successfully returned the XML I was expecting.

Then I tried doing this within the code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    BufferedReader br = null;

    PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://somesite.com/feed");
    method.addParameter("key", "value");

    try {
        int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        String readLine;
        while (((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            System.err.println(readLine);
        }

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(method.getResponseBodyAsStream(), stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
        if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception fe) {}
    }
```

At client.executeMethod, I got a ConnectException: Connection timed out.

Any advice you could give would be much appreciated.

Is there any issue with using different domain http and https - ie if I call this post method from an http page or an https page?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the endpoint exists from the client's perspective ? Is the client running on the same machine that the HTML page test was performed in ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the encoding:

```
new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream(), "windows-1252")
```

`br.close()` before `method.releaseConnection()`

The `IOUtils.copy` copies from an ended stream. Either do not use it, or better use it instead of your own read-loop.

After br.close() or equivalent, use the stringWriter, as then all is flushed.

Comment: Hi. The code does not even get this far. The connection times out at this line: `int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);`

Comment: Try something like `setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)");` for if the server checks for robots. Check for cookies/redirects in the original browser session.

Comment: Turns out it was a proxy issue!